# Crop white space around black image based on color

Tags: c#, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I using Imaemagick and c# and wondering:
Is it possible to crop image to border without exactly sizes?
From first to second?
[First image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RaCju.jpg)

[Second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ad9ae.jpg)

Comment: I can't see any difference between your First and Second image.

Comment: Because they have white background

Comment: convert  1.png  -trim final.png

Answer (score 0):

To remove the white space around the sudoku square you can loop over the pixels. Since the image is black and white it makes it a lot easier because we can check when any of the R, G or B values drop below a certain white threshold and become black.

In this example, I'm just using an arbitrary 200 value to check.

I'm walking in from the top left and bottom right corners. This will only work if your image is always a perfect square. but you can easily adjust this code to check coordinates more accurately to meet your purposes.

```
using (var image = new Bitmap(Image.FromFile("firstImage.jpg")))
{
    int topX = 0, topY = 0;
    int bottomX = image.Width - 1, bottomY = image.Height - 1;

    var color = image.GetPixel(topX, topY);

    while(color.R > 200)
        color = image.GetPixel(++topX, ++topY);

    color = image.GetPixel(bottomX, bottomY);

    while(color.R > 200)
        color = image.GetPixel(--bottomX, --bottomY);

    Bitmap croppedImage = new Bitmap(image);
    Rectangle cropRect = new Rectangle(topX, topY, bottomX - topX + 1, bottomY - topY + 1);
    croppedImage = croppedImage.Clone(cropRect, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    croppedImage.Save("firstImageNoBorder.jpg");
}
```

Original:

[image]

Cropped:

[image]